# SQL server 2000 insert rows when join does not match

Tags: sql-server, insert

I would simply like to insert rows from a table to another if rows does not exist in the target.
How should I code that? with inner join? 
Below is the query which returns rows that match between source and target

```
 select * from LOG_S1201_REFERENCE_T1 b 
 inner join LOG_S1201_REFERENCE_STAGING_WT5 a on b.OU_ID=a.OU_ID     and
 b.Plant_desc=a.Plant_desc   and  b.workshop=a.workshop              and
 b.SerieNum=a.SerieNum       and  b.Operation_type=a.Operation_type  and
 b.PC10DBName=a.PC10DBName   and  b.SimuDBName=a.SimuDBName          and
 b.ProgramName=a.ProgramName and  b.Calibre=a.Calibre
```

Comment: You have to make left join and use is null condition. Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the table that has all rows with left join with the table that has some of the rows.

Filter one of the left joined table column with IS NULL

```
INSERT INTO your_table
select b.* 
from LOG_S1201_REFERENCE_T1 b 
left join LOG_S1201_REFERENCE_STAGING_WT5 a on b.OU_ID=a.OU_ID and b.Plant_desc=a.Plant_desc and b.workshop=a.workshop and b.SerieNum=a.SerieNum and b.Operation_type=a.Operation_type and b.PC10DBName=a.PC10DBName and b.SimuDBName=a.SimuDBName and b.ProgramName=a.ProgramName and b.Calibre=a.Calibre
WHERE a.OU_ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Copying rows can be done through [INSERT SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

Need an example?

```
INSERT INTO new_table (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col4, col5, col6
FROM old_table
HAVING !(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM new_table WHERE col1 = old_table.col4)
```

Comment: yes but actually I want to insert rows that do not match in my inner join statement

Comment: This above query can handle INNER JOIN, just put in after FROM and remove HAVING if you didn't need that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to select rows that do NOT match you need to do a `left join`.

```
INSERT INTO LOG_S1201_REFERENCE_T1 b2 
SELECT a.* FROM LOG_S1201_REFERENCE_STAGING_WT5 a
LEFT JOIN LOG_S1201_REFERENCE_T1 b ON 
   (b.OU_ID=a.OU_ID 
    AND b.Plant_desc=a.Plant_desc 
    AND b.workshop=a.workshop 
    AND b.SerieNum=a.SerieNum
    AND b.Operation_type=a.Operation_type
    AND b.PC10DBName=a.PC10DBName 
    AND b.SimuDBName=a.SimuDBName
    AND b.ProgramName=a.ProgramName 
    AND b.Calibre=a.Calibre)
WHERE b.OU_ID IS NULL
```

This will `select` all rows from `a` that are not in `b` which will then be inserted into `a`.
Afterwards `a` and `b` should be identical  (except for `b` rows that are not in `a`).